# Trying to create javascript to seperate +1 10 digit global numbers with dashes

Tags: javascript

I've found code for 7 and 10 digit numbers but I need to separate for 11.

For example I have numbers as +13138373884 and I need them to display as +1-313-837-3884

example for 10 digit code I found...

```
 var number = this.$el.find('#phoneNumberField').val().replace(/-/g, '');

    if(number.length > 10) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(number.length < 3) {
        number = number; // just for legibility
    } else if(number.length < 7) {
        number = number.substring(0,3) + 
        '-' + 
        number.substring(3,6)
    } else if(number.length > 6) {
        number = number.substring(0,3) + 
        '-' + 
        number.substring(3,6) + 
        '-' + 
        number.substring(6,10);
    }

    this.$el.find('#phoneNumberField').val(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise that everyone needs to start somewhere, but if you want to learn, it's a good idea not to expect a web search to turn up code that *exactly meets your requirements*. Instead, spend some time understanding and adapting the code you do find.

In this case, have a look at those numbers in brackets after "substring". How might they relate to the result? What happens if you change them?

A great resource for learning JS and web programming in general is MDN. Try
If you need to [looking up "substring" there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Substring).

(If you don't want to learn, and just want someone to do the work for you, pay them.)